# fullcalendar disappears when using Livewire wire:poll

Tags: fullcalendar, laravel-livewire

I am work on a project that make use of fullcalendar for appointments. What I'm trying to accomplish is to keep the evennts in the calendar uptodate.

I decided to use livewire which makes things easy.
Everything is working fine. But becausue I am using wire:poll in my livewire component, the contents of the component get's refreshed to keep things updated all the time.

The problem is, immediately the component refreshes, fullcalendar completely vanishes from the page.

ofcourse other data on the page gets updated without an issue.
**How do I solve this. What am I doing wrong. Or is there a better way to handle this?**

Here my Code:

Livewire component class:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Visitor\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Modules\Visitor\app\Models\Appointment;

class FrontendCalendar extends Component
{
  public $events;

  public function render()
  {
    $today_appointments = Appointment::where('status', 0)->whereDate('created_at','>=', Carbon::today())->latest()->get();
    $pending_appointments = Appointment::where('status', 0)->whereDate('created_at','<', Carbon::today())->latest()->get();
    $appointments_events = Appointment::where('status', 0)->latest()->get()->map(function($item){
      return [
        'id' => $item->id,
        'title' => $item->name,
        'start' => format_date($item->start_date),
        'end' => format_date($item->end_date),
        'extendedProps' => [
          'calendar' => $item->color ?? 'primary',
          'fullname' => $item->name,
          'phone' => $item->phone,
          'email' => $item->email,
          'address' => $item->address,
          'gender' => $item->gender,
          'purpose' => $item->purpose,
          'status' => $item->status,
          'start_date' => $item->start_date,
          'end_date' => $item->end_date,
          'color' => $item->color?? 'primary',
        ]
      ];
    });
    $this->dispatch('refreshCalender', ($appointments_events));
    return view('visitor::livewire.frontend-calendar',compact(
      'today_appointments','pending_appointments','appointments_events'
    ));
  }
}
```

Livewire view:
**livewire.frontend-calendar**

```
<div wire:poll.keep-alive>

  <div class="card app-calendar-wrapper">
    <div class="row g-0">
    <!-- Calendar -->
    <div class="col app-calendar-content">
      <div class="card shadow-none border-0 border-start rounded-0">
        <div class="card-body pb-0">
          <!-- FullCalendar -->
          <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="app-overlay"></div>
      <!-- FullCalendar Offcanvas -->
      @include('visitor::offcanvas')
    </div>
    <!-- /Calendar -->
    <!-- Calendar Sidebar -->
    <div class="col app-calendar-sidebar pt-1" id="app-calendar-sidebar">
      {{-- <div class="p-3 pb-2 my-sm-0 mb-3">
        <div class="d-grid">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle-sidebar" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#addEventSidebar" aria-controls="addEventSidebar">
            <i class="mdi mdi-plus me-1"></i>
            <span class="align-middle">Add Appointment</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div> --}}
      <div class="p-4">
        @if (!empty($today_appointments) && ($today_appointments->count() > 0))
        <h4>Today</h4>
        <hr class="container-m-nx my-4">
        <ul style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 200px;" class="p-0 m-0">
          @foreach ($today_appointments as $item)
          <li class="d-flex shadow-sm p-1 rounded mb-4">
            <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0 me-3">
              @if (substr($item->gender,0,1) == 'M')
              <img src="{{asset('assets/img/avatars/1.png')}}" alt="avatar" class="rounded">
              @else
              <img src="{{asset('assets/img/avatars/8.png')}}" alt="avatar" class="rounded">
              @endif
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex w-100 flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between gap-2">
              <div class="me-2">
                <h6 class="mb-0 fw-semibold text-nowrap"><small><span class="badge bg-label-success rounded-pill"><i class="tf-icons mdi mdi-circle mdi-14px"></i></span> <span>{{$item->name}}</span></small></h6>
                <small class="text-muted">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-calendar-blank-outline mdi-14px"></i>
                  <span>{{$item->start_date}} |{{$item->end_date}}</span>
                </small>
                <p>{{$item->purpose}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <hr>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
        <hr class="container-m-nx my-4">
        @endif
        @if (!empty($pending_appointments) && ($pending_appointments->count() > 0))

        <h4>Upcoming</h4>
        <hr class="container-m-nx my-4">
        <ul style="overflow-y: scroll;height: 300px; overflow-x:hidden" class="p-0 m-0">
          @foreach ($pending_appointments as $item)
          <li class="d-flex shadow-sm p-1 rounded mb-4">
            <div class="avatar flex-shrink-0 me-3">
              @if (substr($item->gender,0,1) == 'M')
              <img src="{{asset('assets/img/avatars/1.png')}}" alt="avatar" class="rounded">
              @else
              <img src="{{asset('assets/img/avatars/8.png')}}" alt="avatar" class="rounded">
              @endif
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex w-100 flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between gap-2">
              <div class="me-2">
                <h6 class="mb-0 fw-semibold text-nowrap"><small><span class="badge bg-label-success rounded-pill"><i class="tf-icons mdi mdi-circle mdi-14px"></i></span> <span>{{$item->name}}</span></small></h6>
                <small class="text-muted">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-calendar-blank-outline mdi-14px"></i>
                  <span>{{$item->start_date}} |{{$item->end_date}}</span>
                </small>
                <p>{{$item->purpose}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <hr>
          @endforeach
        </ul>
        @endif
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Calendar Sidebar -->
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

@push('page-script')
<script>
  'use strict';
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    (function () {
      let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'),
        appCalendarSidebar = document.querySelector('.app-calendar-sidebar'),
        offcanvasAddAppointment = document.getElementById('addEventSidebar'),
        appOverlay = document.querySelector('.app-overlay'),
        offcanvasTitle = document.querySelector('.offcanvas-title'),
        btnToggleSidebar = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle-sidebar'),
        btnSubmit = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]'),
        btnCancel = document.querySelector('.btn-cancel'),
        selectAll = document.querySelector('.select-all'),
        inlineCalendar = document.querySelector('.inline-calendar');

      let eventToUpdate, inlineCalInstance;
      const bsoffcanvasAddAppointment = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(offcanvasAddAppointment);

      // Inline sidebar calendar (flatpicker)
      if (inlineCalendar) {
        inlineCalInstance = inlineCalendar.flatpickr({
          monthSelectorType: 'static',
          inline: true
        });
      }
      function eventClick(info) {
        eventToUpdate = info.event;
        var appointment_id = appointment_id;

        bsoffcanvasAddAppointment.show();
        if (offcanvasTitle) {
          offcanvasTitle.innerHTML = 'Update Appointment';
        }
        btnSubmit.innerHTML = 'Update';
        btnSubmit.classList.add('btn-update-event');
        btnSubmit.classList.remove('btn-add-event');

        var data = eventToUpdate.extendedProps;
        $('#appointment_id').val(eventToUpdate.id);
        $('#fullname').val(data.fullname);
        $('#phone').val(data.phone);
        $('#email').val(data.email);
        $('#address').val(data.address);
        $('#gender').val(data.gender);
        $('#purpose').val(data.purpose);
        $('#startDate').val(data.start_date);
        $('#endDate').val(data.end_date);
        $('#status').val(data.status).trigger('change');

      }

      function modifyToggler() {
        const fcSidebarToggleButton = document.querySelector('.fc-sidebarToggle-button');
        if (fcSidebarToggleButton) {
          fcSidebarToggleButton.classList.remove('fc-button-primary');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.classList.add('d-lg-none', 'd-inline-block', 'ps-0');
          while (fcSidebarToggleButton.firstChild) {
            fcSidebarToggleButton.firstChild.remove();
          }
          fcSidebarToggleButton.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'sidebar');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.setAttribute('data-overlay', '');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.setAttribute('data-target', '#app-calendar-sidebar');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="mdi mdi-menu mdi-24px text-body"></i>');
        }
      }

      let eventsData = @json($appointments_events)

      Livewire.on('refreshCalender', (e) => {
        eventsData = { ...e }[0]
        console.log(eventsData);
      })
      let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events: eventsData,
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timegridPlugin],
        editable: true,
        dragScroll: true,
        eventResizableFromStart: true,
        customButtons: {
          sidebarToggle: {
            text: 'Sidebar'
          }
        },
        headerToolbar: {
          start: 'sidebarToggle, prev,next, title',
          end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
        },
        loading: function(isLoading) {
          if (!isLoading) {
              this.getEvents().forEach(function(e){
                if (e.source === null) {
                    e.remove();
                }
              });
          }
        },
        initialDate: new Date(),
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        eventClassNames: function ({ event: calendarEvent }) {
          const colorName = calendarEvent._def.extendedProps.color;
          // Background Color
          return ['fc-event-' + colorName];
        },
        dateClick: function (info) {
          let date = moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          bsoffcanvasAddAppointment.show();

          if (offcanvasTitle) {
            offcanvasTitle.innerHTML = 'Add Appointment';
          }
          btnSubmit.innerHTML = 'Add';
          btnSubmit.classList.remove('btn-update-event');
          btnSubmit.classList.add('btn-add-event');
        },
        eventClick: function (info) {
          eventClick(info);
        },
        datesSet: function () {
          modifyToggler();
        },
        viewDidMount: function () {
          modifyToggler();
        }
      });
      calendar.render();



      // Modify sidebar toggler
      modifyToggler();

      // Hide left sidebar if the right sidebar is open
      if (btnToggleSidebar) {
        btnToggleSidebar.addEventListener('click', e => {
          if (offcanvasTitle) {
            offcanvasTitle.innerHTML = 'Add Appointment';
          }
          btnSubmit.innerHTML = 'Add';
          btnSubmit.classList.remove('btn-update-event');
          btnSubmit.classList.add('btn-add-event');
          appCalendarSidebar.classList.remove('show');
          appOverlay.classList.remove('show');
        });
      }

      if(inlineCalInstance){
        inlineCalInstance.config.onChange.push(function (date) {
          calendar.changeView(calendar.view.type, moment(date[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          modifyToggler();
          appCalendarSidebar.classList.remove('show');
          appOverlay.classList.remove('show');
        });

      }
    })();
  });
</script>
@endpush
```

**Main page that displays the calendar**

```
@extends('layouts.layoutMaster')

@section('title', 'Appointments - Calendar View')

@section('vendor-style')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/libs/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css')}}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/libs/flatpickr/flatpickr.css')}}" />
@endsection

@section('page-style')
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendor/css/pages/app-calendar.css')}}" />
@endsection


@section('content')
<livewire:visitor::frontend-calendar />
@endsection


@section('vendor-script')
<script src="{{asset('assets/vendor/libs/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/vendor/libs/flatpickr/flatpickr.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/vendor/libs/moment/moment.js')}}"></script>
@endsection
```

I should mention that, the **@push('page-script')** is rendered under the **@section('vendor-script')** in the page.
Thanks in advance

I expect the calendar to be rendered with the new events without disappearing on me.

I've also tried using the answer mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550522/laravel-livewire-javascript-data-is-not-refreshed-after-component-is-re-rendered)  but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be twofold. Firstly, your script is being pushed multiple times into the **'page-script'** stack. This means that every time your component is refreshed, the same script is being pushed into the stack. Secondly, if you cannot use **wire:ignore**, you may need to reinitialize FullCalendar whenever your component is refreshed. You can achieve this with the help of *Livewire Events*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've tried using the wire:ignore on the calendar parent div. The calendar didn't disappear but my data didn't also update. the events remained the same

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that might have a similar issue,
These are the changes I made to the livewire component.
I added wire:ignore to the calendar parent div

```
<div class="card-body pb-0" wire:ignore>
          <div id="calendar"></div>
        </div>
```

I changed my events attribute to a feed

```
events: {
            url: "{{route('frontend.fetch-calendar-events')}}",
            extraParams: function() {
              return {
                cachebuster: new Date().valueOf()
              };
            }
          },
```

And Then called ** calendar.refetchEvents()** when the event is fired

```
Livewire.on('refreshCalender', (e) => {
        calendar.refetchEvents()
      })
```

This is now my scripts

```
@push('page-script')
<script>
  'use strict';
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    (function () {
      let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar'),
        appCalendarSidebar = document.querySelector('.app-calendar-sidebar'),
        offcanvasAddAppointment = document.getElementById('addEventSidebar'),
        appOverlay = document.querySelector('.app-overlay'),
        offcanvasTitle = document.querySelector('.offcanvas-title'),
        btnToggleSidebar = document.querySelector('.btn-toggle-sidebar'),
        btnSubmit = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]'),
        btnCancel = document.querySelector('.btn-cancel'),
        selectAll = document.querySelector('.select-all'),
        inlineCalendar = document.querySelector('.inline-calendar');

      let eventToUpdate, inlineCalInstance;
      const bsoffcanvasAddAppointment = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(offcanvasAddAppointment);
      if (inlineCalendar) {
        inlineCalInstance = inlineCalendar.flatpickr({
          monthSelectorType: 'static',
          inline: true
        });
      }
      function eventClick(info) {
        eventToUpdate = info.event;
        var appointment_id = appointment_id;

        bsoffcanvasAddAppointment.show();
        if (offcanvasTitle) {
          offcanvasTitle.innerHTML = 'Update Appointment';
        }
        btnSubmit.innerHTML = 'Update';
        btnSubmit.classList.add('btn-update-event');
        btnSubmit.classList.remove('btn-add-event');

        var data = eventToUpdate.extendedProps;
        $('#appointment_id').val(eventToUpdate.id);
        $('#fullname').val(data.fullname);
        $('#phone').val(data.phone);
        $('#email').val(data.email);
        $('#address').val(data.address);
        $('#gender').val(data.gender);
        $('#purpose').val(data.purpose);
        $('#startDate').val(data.start_date);
        $('#endDate').val(data.end_date);
        $('#status').val(data.status).trigger('change');

      }

      function modifyToggler() {
        const fcSidebarToggleButton = document.querySelector('.fc-sidebarToggle-button');
        if (fcSidebarToggleButton) {
          fcSidebarToggleButton.classList.remove('fc-button-primary');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.classList.add('d-lg-none', 'd-inline-block', 'ps-0');
          while (fcSidebarToggleButton.firstChild) {
            fcSidebarToggleButton.firstChild.remove();
          }
          fcSidebarToggleButton.setAttribute('data-bs-toggle', 'sidebar');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.setAttribute('data-overlay', '');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.setAttribute('data-target', '#app-calendar-sidebar');
          fcSidebarToggleButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="mdi mdi-menu mdi-24px text-body"></i>');
        }
      }

      function initializeCalendar(calendarEl){
        return new Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
          events: {
            url: "{{route('frontend.fetch-calendar-events')}}",
            extraParams: function() {
              return {
                cachebuster: new Date().valueOf()
              };
            }
          },
          plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, timegridPlugin],
          editable: true,
          dragScroll: true,
          eventResizableFromStart: true,
          customButtons: {
            sidebarToggle: {
              text: 'Sidebar'
            }
          },
          headerToolbar: {
            start: 'sidebarToggle, prev,next, title',
            end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
          },
          loading: function(isLoading) {
            if (!isLoading) {
                this.getEvents().forEach(function(e){
                  if (e.source === null) {
                      e.remove();
                  }
                });
            }
          },
          initialDate: new Date(),
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          eventClassNames: function ({ event: calendarEvent }) {
            const colorName = calendarEvent._def.extendedProps.color;
            // Background Color
            return ['fc-event-' + colorName];
          },
          dateClick: function (info) {
            let date = moment(info.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
            bsoffcanvasAddAppointment.show();

            if (offcanvasTitle) {
              offcanvasTitle.innerHTML = 'Add Appointment';
            }
            btnSubmit.innerHTML = 'Add';
            btnSubmit.classList.remove('btn-update-event');
            btnSubmit.classList.add('btn-add-event');
          },
          eventClick: function (info) {
            eventClick(info);
          },
          datesSet: function () {
            modifyToggler();
          },
          viewDidMount: function () {
            modifyToggler();
          }
        });
      }

      let calendar = initializeCalendar(calendarEl)
      calendar.render();

      Livewire.on('refreshCalender', (e) => {
        calendar.refetchEvents()
      })
      modifyToggler();
      // Hide left sidebar if the right sidebar is open
      if (btnToggleSidebar) {
        btnToggleSidebar.addEventListener('click', e => {
          if (offcanvasTitle) {
            offcanvasTitle.innerHTML = 'Add Appointment';
          }
          btnSubmit.innerHTML = 'Add';
          btnSubmit.classList.remove('btn-update-event');
          btnSubmit.classList.add('btn-add-event');
          appCalendarSidebar.classList.remove('show');
          appOverlay.classList.remove('show');
        });
      }

      if(inlineCalInstance){
        inlineCalInstance.config.onChange.push(function (date) {
          calendar.changeView(calendar.view.type, moment(date[0]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
          modifyToggler();
          appCalendarSidebar.classList.remove('show');
          appOverlay.classList.remove('show');
        });

      }
    })();
  });
</script>
@endpush
```